# Change watermark text to a watermark image

Tags: javascript, css, image, printing, text-editor

I have a [text-editor](https://unripened-amperes.000webhostapp.com/)

and I want when the user print the text in it ,the printed page to have a watermark and when i tried it with text watermark it works but with image watermark it does not work and here is the print script

```js
function printDoc() {
 if (!validateMode()) { return; }
var printContents = document.getElementById('textBox').innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents+'<div style="width:150px;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;opacity:.5;">Display Logo Here...</div>';
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

and even when i tried to put watermark before printContents it does not work at all and here is the full script of the text-editor [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/0jnw95v2/)

```js
var oDoc, sDefTxt;

function initDoc() {
  oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
  sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
  if (document.compForm.switchMode.checked) {
    setDocMode(true);
  }
}

function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {
  if (validateMode()) {
    document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue);
    oDoc.focus();
  }
}

function validateMode() {
  if (!document.compForm.switchMode.checked) {
    return true;
  }
  alert("Uncheck \"Show HTML\".");
  oDoc.focus();
  return false;
}

function setDocMode(bToSource) {
  var oContent;
  if (bToSource) {
    oContent = document.createTextNode(oDoc.innerHTML);
    oDoc.innerHTML = "";
    var oPre = document.createElement("pre");
    oDoc.contentEditable = false;
    oPre.id = "sourceText";
    oPre.contentEditable = true;
    oPre.appendChild(oContent);
    oDoc.appendChild(oPre);
    document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "div");
  } else {
    if (document.all) {
      oDoc.innerHTML = oDoc.innerText;
    } else {
      oContent = document.createRange();
      oContent.selectNodeContents(oDoc.firstChild);
      oDoc.innerHTML = oContent.toString();
    }
    oDoc.contentEditable = true;
  }
  oDoc.focus();
}




function printDoc() {
  if (!validateMode()) {
    return;
  }
  // Add your watermark here  
  var WaterMark = '<div style="width:150px;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;opacity:.8;">StackOverFlow</div>';
  var printContents = document.getElementById('textBox').innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents + WaterMark;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
/*page margin*/
var cssPagedMedia = (function() {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  return function(rule) {
    style.innerHTML = rule;
  };
}());

cssPagedMedia.margin = function(margin) {
  cssPagedMedia('@page {margin: ' + margin + '}');
};

cssPagedMedia.margin('0');
/*page size*/
cssPagedMedia.size = function(size) {
  cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};

var cssPagedMedia = (function() {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  return function(rule) {
    style.innerHTML = rule;
  };
}());
cssPagedMedia.size = function(size) {
  cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
};
cssPagedMedia.size('portrait');
```

```css
.intLink {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.intLink {
  border: 0;
}

#toolBar1 select {
  font-size: 10px;
}

#textBox {
  width: 540px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#textBox #sourceText {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 498px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

#editMode label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="printa">

  <body onload="initDoc();">
    <form name="compForm" method="post" action="sample.php" onsubmit="if(validateMode()){this.myDoc.value=oDoc.innerHTML;return true;}return false;">
      <input type="hidden" name="myDoc">
      <div id="toolBar1">
        <select onchange="formatDoc('formatblock',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option selected>- التنسيق -</option>
          <option value="h1">عنوان 1 &lt;h1&gt;</option>
          <option value="h2">عنوان 2 &lt;h2&gt;</option>
          <option value="h3">عنوان 3 &lt;h3&gt;</option>
          <option value="h4">عنوان 4 &lt;h4&gt;</option>
          <option value="h5">عنوان 5 &lt;h5&gt;</option>
          <option value="h6">عنوان فرعي &lt;h6&gt;</option>
          <option value="p">فقرة &lt;p&gt;</option>
          <option value="pre">مهيأ مسبقا &lt;pre&gt;</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('fontname',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- الخطوط -</option>
          <option>Arial</option>
          <option>Arial Black</option>
          <option>Courier New</option>
          <option>Times New Roman</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('fontsize',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- الحجم -</option>
          <option value="1">صغير جدا</option>
          <option value="2">صغير بعض الشيء</option>
          <option value="3">عادي</option>
          <option value="4">متوسط - كبير</option>
          <option value="5">كبير</option>
          <option value="6">كبير جدا</option>
          <option value="7">أقصى</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('forecolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- اللون -</option>
          <option value="red">أحمر</option>
          <option value="blue">أزرق</option>
          <option value="green">أخضر</option>
          <option value="black">أسود</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('backcolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- الخلفية -</option>
          <option value="red">أحمر</option>
          <option value="green">أخضر</option>
          <option value="black">أسود</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="toolBar2">
        <img class="intLink" title="طباعة" onclick="printDoc();" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <img class="intLink" title="خط عريض " onclick="formatDoc('bold');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAInhI+pa+H9mJy0LhdgtrxzDG5WGFVk6aXqyk6Y9kXvKKNuLbb6zgMFADs=" />
        <img class="intLink" title="خط مائل" onclick="formatDoc('italic');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKEDAAAAAF9vj5WIbf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAAWABYAAAIjnI+py+0Po5x0gXvruEKHrF2BB1YiCWgbMFIYpsbyTNd2UwAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="تسطير" onclick="formatDoc('underline');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKECAAAAAF9vj////////yH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAWABYAAAIrlI+py+0Po5zUgAsEzvEeL4Ea15EiJJ5PSqJmuwKBEKgxVuXWtun+DwxCCgA7" />
        <img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى اليسار" onclick="formatDoc('justifyleft');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JMGELkGYxo+qzl4nKyXAAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى الوسط" onclick="formatDoc('justifycenter');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIfhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JOGI7kaZ5Bqn4sycVbAQA7" />
        <img class="intLink" title="محاذاة إلى اليمين" onclick="formatDoc('justifyright');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JQGDLkGYxouqzl43JyVgAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="الرجوع إلى الخلف" onclick="formatDoc('undo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKADljwliE33mOrpGjuYKl8aezxqPD+7/I19DV3NHa7P///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARR8MlJq7046807TkaYeJJBnES4EeUJvIGapWYAC0CsocQ7SDlWJkAkCA6ToMYWIARGQF3mRQVIEjkkSVLIbSfEwhdRIH4fh/DZMICe3/C4nBQBADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="التقدم إلى الأمام" onclick="formatDoc('redo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIHAB1ChDljwl9vj1iE34Kl8aPD+7/I1////yH5BAEKAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAANKeLrc/jDKSesyphi7SiEgsVXZEATDICqBVJjpqWZt9NaEDNbQK1wCQsxlYnxMAImhyDoFAElJasRRvAZVRqqQXUy7Cgx4TC6bswkAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="قائمة ذات تعداد رقمي" onclick="formatDoc('insertorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAADljwliE35GjuaezxtHa7P///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAM2eLrc/jDKSespwjoRFvggCBUBoTFBeq6QIAysQnRHaEOzyaZ07Lu9lUBnC0UGQU1K52s6n5oEADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="قائمة ذات تعداد نقطي" onclick="formatDoc('insertunorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAAB1ChF9vj1iE33mOrqezxv///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAMyeLrc/jDKSesppNhGRlBAKIZRERBbqm6YtnbfMY7lud64UwiuKnigGQliQuWOyKQykgAAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="إضافة رابط" onclick="var sLnk=prompt('Write the URL here','http:\/\/');if(sLnk&&sLnk!=''&&sLnk!='http://'){formatDoc('createlink',sLnk)}" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKAB1ChDRLY19vj3mOrpGjuaezxrCztb/I19Ha7Pv8/f///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARY8MlJq7046827/2BYIQVhHg9pEgVGIklyDEUBy/RlE4FQF4dCj2AQXAiJQDCWQCAEBwIioEMQBgSAFhDAGghGi9XgHAhMNoSZgJkJei33UESv2+/4vD4TAQA7"
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="القص" onclick="formatDoc('cut');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQSAB1ChBFNsRJTySJYwjljwkxwl19vj1dusYODhl6MnHmOrpqbmpGjuaezxrCztcDCxL/I18rL1P///////////////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAVu4CeOZGmeaKqubDs6TNnEbGNApNG0kbGMi5trwcA9GArXh+FAfBAw5UexUDAQESkRsfhJPwaH4YsEGAAJGisRGAQY7UCC9ZAXBB+74LGCRxIEHwAHdWooDgGJcwpxDisQBQRjIgkDCVlfmZqbmiEAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="النسخ" onclick="formatDoc('copy');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQcAB1ChBFNsTRLYyJYwjljwl9vj1iE31iGzF6MnHWX9HOdz5GjuYCl2YKl8ZOt4qezxqK63aK/9KPD+7DI3b/I17LM/MrL1MLY9NHa7OPs++bx/Pv8/f///////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWG4CeOZGmeaKqubOum1SQ/kPVOW749BeVSus2CgrCxHptLBbOQxCSNCCaF1GUqwQbBd0JGJAyGJJiobE+LnCaDcXAaEoxhQACgNw0FQx9kP+wmaRgYFBQNeAoGihCAJQsCkJAKOhgXEw8BLQYciooHf5o7EA+kC40qBKkAAAGrpy+wsbKzIiEAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="اللصق" onclick="formatDoc('paste');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQUAD04KTRLY2tXQF9vj414WZWIbXmOrpqbmpGjudClFaezxsa0cb/I1+3YitHa7PrkIPHvbuPs+/fvrvv8/f///////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWN4CeOZGmeaKqubGsusPvBSyFJjVDs6nJLB0khR4AkBCmfsCGBQAoCwjF5gwquVykSFbwZE+AwIBV0GhFog2EwIDchjwRiQo9E2Fx4XD5R+B0DDAEnBXBhBhN2DgwDAQFjJYVhCQYRfgoIDGiQJAWTCQMRiwwMfgicnVcAAAMOaK+bLAOrtLUyt7i5uiUhADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="المسح التام" onclick="if(validateMode()&&confirm('Are you sure?')){oDoc.innerHTML=sDefTxt};" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQbAD04KTRLYzFRjlldZl9vj1dusY14WYODhpWIbbSVFY6O7IOXw5qbms+wUbCztca0ccS4kdDQjdTLtMrL1O3YitHa7OPcsd/f4PfvrvDv8Pv5xv///////////////////yH5BAEKAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAV84CeOZGmeaKqubMteyzK547QoBcFWTm/jgsHq4rhMLoxFIehQQSAWR+Z4IAyaJ0kEgtFoLIzLwRE4oCQWrxoTOTAIhMCZ0tVgMBQKZHAYyFEWEV14eQ8IflhnEHmFDQkAiSkQCI2PDC4QBg+OAJc0ewadNCOgo6anqKkoIQA7"
        />

      </div>
      <iframe id="inlineFrameExample" name="inlineFrameExample" title="Inline Frame Example" width="0" height="0" dir="rtl" hidden="hidden">
  </iframe>
      <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true">


        <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/KDXSnOv.jpg" width="160"></div><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Lorem Ipsum</strong>
        <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
          has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
      </div>

      <p id="editMode"><input type="checkbox" name="switchMode" id="switchBox" onchange="setDocMode(this.checked);" hidden="hidden" /> </p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Send" hidden="hidden" /></p>
```

What should I do to add img as a watermark into the printed page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do this with stylesheets that target printing.

## Demo

https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/SO53360134

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
    <img id="watermark" src="logo.png" alt="A watermark you can only see when you print" />
    <section>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id sapien et sem lobortis pharetra at vitae orci. Nullam ipsum velit, sollicitudin ac fringilla et, interdum elementum quam. Donec magna augue, dignissim vitae finibus faucibus, hendrerit quis libero. In quis quam pulvinar lacus faucibus convallis sit amet at enim. Etiam varius urna vitae sem tristique, eget placerat turpis semper. Quisque dictum purus sit amet metus venenatis vehicula. Etiam ac ex at dui imperdiet lobortis eget eget augue. Quisque fermentum aliquam condimentum. Nulla eget enim auctor, venenatis metus sit amet, aliquet turpis. Proin id pretium risus.
      </p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

## CSS (link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css")

```
#watermark {
  display: none;
}
```

## CSS (link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print")

```
#watermark {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

## Inline style (alternative)

```
<style type="text/css">
  #watermark { display: none; }
  @media print {
    #watermark {
      display: block;
      width: 150px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 5px;
      right: 5px;
      opacity: .5;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: how can i put your whole script togather without using files i tried to replace link href with id="printo" and #watermark with #printo and i did the same with style using id="stylo" #stylo and the printed page have the watermark but the same watermark appear all over the website page so how can i hide using #stylo or should i apply two IDs or id+class on the img like #print .style and put css in {}

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following what you're saying. You're on here asking for advice on how to change code, but you can't change code? Or you can, but you just can't upload files? If that's the case, I'll add some info to my answer about inline print stylesheets

Comment: Here, I updated it for you with what I provided in my answer above. https://jsfiddle.net/dbjh5me1/

Comment: You have just changed css only or you have changed someting else ?

Comment: Only the CSS. The first 12 lines

Comment: The script works very well on its own like in this website [test](https://unripened-amperes.000webhostapp.com/) but when I embed it in blogger it does not function very well [blogger](https://justanothertestwebsite.blogspot.com/2018/11/text-editor-final-version.html) do have any idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183848/discussion-between-anonymoussb-and-hamid).